# Why would Perl's printf output the format specifier rather than the formatted number?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to debug a problem on a remote user's site. We've narrowed it down to a problem with formatted output in Perl. The user swears up and down that

```
perl -e 'printf "Number: %lG\n", 0.1'
```

prints

```
Number: %lG
```

not

```
Number: 0.1
```

The user reports that their Perl is version 5.8. The oldest version I have around is 5.8.1, and it seems to behave correctly.

Any guesses? Misconfiguration? Module conflicts?

Comment: User error, replace user and try again.

Comment: You should use single quotes around that format specifier, so `%lG` doesn't accidentally interpolate into the contents of the hash named `%lG`.

Comment: You should check they didn't use print instead of printf.

Comment: Ether: $ and @ interpolate, not %.  You'd need something like print "@{[ %lG ]}"; to make that happen. From perlop: For constructs that do interpolate, variables beginning with ""$"" or ""@"" are interpolated.  Subscripted variables such as $a[3] or "$href->{key}[0]" are also interpolated, as are array and hash slices.  But method calls such as "$obj->meth" are not.

Comment: @MkV, thanks for your input. Unfortunately for me, it really doesn't look like user error. A script that is known to work correctly on other machines is showing the same issue on the user's machine. The inline script I gave is just the simplest repro case. Do you know if there are configuration options in the perl build that could turn support for long floats off?

Comment: If your compiler supports long doubles then the argument will be cast into a long double, otherwise it will be cast into a double (perl internally uses doubles, not floats).  In neither case would %lG fail.  %llG (2 ls) would fail if the compiler lacked support for long doubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>It looks like it was a Perl build configuration issue. The Perl build supports a `d_longdbl` option, which indicates whether long doubles are allowed or not. You can test whether it is set on your machine with:</del>

```
perl -V:d_longdbl
```

More info at [perldoc sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).
Thanks for your input everybody.

---

Edit:

Nope, that wasn't it either. Close inspection of the sprintf documentation revealed that the modifiers for a long double are `q`, `ll`, and `L`, **NOT** `l`. `l` is a valid modifer for integer types. D'oh.

It looks like most installations of perl will silently ignore the `l`, and parse the rest of the modifier correctly. Except on our user's site. ☹ Anyway, the problem was fixed by using a valid modifier for a long double.

FYI, I played with the same format specifiers in the C `printf`.

```
printf("The number is %lG\n", 0.001);
printf("The number is %LG\n", 0.001);
```

The first call “worked”, printing out `0.001`, but the second call printed out a garbage value until I properly specified the type of the numeric literal:

```
printf("The number is %LG\n", 0.001L);
```

Apparently the C `printf` is silently ignoring the improper `l` modifier. This makes me suspect that most Perl installations ignore it too.

Comment: Your answer is the best fit for the question. Go ahead an accept it instead of mine so that it is placed at the top where it belongs.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from the [`sprintf`](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) documentation:

> Returns a string formatted by the usual `printf` conventions of the C library
>   function `sprintf`. See below for more details and see `sprintf(3)` or
>   `printf(3)` on your system for an explanation of the general principles.

IOW, like with many built-ins, Perl just thinly wraps a function, and it's
platform dependent.

> Perl's `sprintf` permits the following universally-known conversions:

`%l` is not part of it. My guess is that the remote user is not using GNU. He can find out exactly what is supported by his unwashed Unix by typing `man 3 sprintf` or `man 3 printf`.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll be glad when all the non-GNU systems disappear :-) +1.

Comment: Also quoting from sprintf documentation, should have read a little closer daxim: Perl does its own "sprintf" formatting -it emulates the C function "sprintf", but it doesn't use it (except for floating-point numbers, and even then only the standard modifiers are allowed).  As a result, any non-standard  extensions in your local "sprintf" are not available from Perl.

Comment: %lG is supported by sprintf: %G   like %g, but with an upper-case "E" (if applicable); and (under size): 'l  interpret integer as C type "long" or "unsigned long"

Comment: %lG is a valid format in POSIX/Single Unix Specification.  Just because GNU sometimes copies from POSIX correctly doesn't make it better.

Comment: Actually it looks like %lG is not a valid specifier. %ld is ok, or %llG, but not %lG. See my answer for details. Daxim's answer is pretty close to the actual problem. Not a GNU/Posix issue though, just an incorrect specifier.

Answer (score 4):

It should only do that if it doesn't recognise the format specifier. For example:

```
pax> perl -e 'printf "Number: %q\n", 0.1'
Number: %q
```

I think you're going to have to go on site to figure this one out although you may want to first get them to cut and paste the text and a screen dump from, for example, [HyperSnap](http://www.hyperionics.com/) demo, into an email so you can check it carefully. I only suggest that one since we use it internally and it has a free trial. You can use any decent screen capture program you like.

I originally thought that they may be typing in `1G` (wun jee) instead of `lG` (ell jee) but the former still works.

I do notice the `IG` (eye jee) will print out the text rather than the number but, unless they're using a particularly bad font, that should be a recognisable difference.

BTW, I only have 5.10 to work with so it *may* be a version problem. It's hard to imagine, however, that there'd be a major difference between 5.8 and 5.8.1.

Comment: @MkV, thanks for checking that in 5.6. It's very helpful to know that.